# magento 1.9.2 community - admin usps missing from carrier dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9

I've never been able to get USPS to show up in the drop-down box. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Is Expendited Shipping is third party shipping method ? or Can you check if United States Postal Service is not renamed to Expendited Shipping ?

Comment: Thanks Akhilesh, that was it!  I renamed the USPS module in the admin section from "Expedited Shipping" back to USPS.

Thanks again!

Comment: Great, Adding my comment in answer box. Accept it, if that is worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if "United States Postal Service" is not renamed to "Expendited Shipping".